# Table and Primary Key sizes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, index, database-tuning, database-size

I am analyzing the size of some tables in Oracle, and I noticed that the primary key occupies almost the same size of its related table.

To be clear, my statistics are the following (approx.):

```
NAME        | TYPE  | SIZE
----------------------------
MYTABLE     | TABLE | 21 GiB
PK_MYTABLE  | INDEX | 20 GiB
```

MYTABLE has four columns, and three of them composes the primary key.  So the sizes should be correct.

- But why do Oracle stores this so inefficiently?  (a separated structure for the primary key)
- Do Oracle has something similar to MS SQL's clustered index, that makes the index *part* of the related table?
- Is there something I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why do Oracle stores this so inefficiently? (a separated structure
>   for the primary key)

It is inefficient for this use case.

> Do Oracle has something similar to MS SQL's clustered index, that
>   makes the index part of the related table?

It is called IOT (Index-organized Table) in Oracle.

[Overview of Index-Organized Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/CNCPT/indexes-and-index-organized-tables.htm#CNCPT88853)

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
 c1 number,
 c2 number,
 c3 number,
 c4 number,
 CONSTRAINT pk_mytable PRIMARY KEY (c1,c2,c3)
)
ORGANIZATION INDEX 
;
```

With this, you will have only one segment caled `PK_MYTABLE`.

> Is there something I can do to avoid this?

See above.